# Two data grid combined as one and how to set the data grid editable when another one error occured

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

I created 2 data grids and located them both side by side. The data grid allows the user to edit and when the value range "0 > input" or "100 < input", an error icon will be displayed.

However, when the data grid 1 error has occurred, the user is still able to edit the data grid 2. How to do when 1 of the data grid error has occurred, the user is unable to edit another data grid? Any suggestions for this case or proper fixed for this?

Using WPFToolKit Data Grid, because current project version is .Net 3.5

Target data grid view
[image]

[Download Project](http://1drv.ms/1gEByky)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WPF `DataGrid` has an `IsReadOnly` property that you can set to `True` to ensure that users cannot edit your DataGrid's cells.

You can bound some boolean to `IsReadOnly`property of both the grids, it will change in case the input (that is also bound I suppose) is out of range (you can set this kind of behavior in the `input` setter)

Code snipt:

```
public class SomeViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     // INotifyPropertyChanged members
     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

     public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
     {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
               PropertyChanged(this, e);
     }

     // Input property
     private string _input;

     public string InputGrid1
     {
       get
       {
            return _input;
       }
       set
       {
           if (value < 0 || value > 100 )
           {
              IsEditable = true;
           }

           _input= value;
           OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("InputGrid1"));
       }
     }

     // ... The same for InputGrid2

     // bool property
     private bool _isEditable;

     public bool IsEditable
     {
       get
       {
            return _isEditable;
       }
       set
       {
           _input= _isEditable;
           OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsEditable"));
       }
     }
}
```

WPF code snippet:

```
  <DataGrid
       DataContext="{StaticResource SomeViewModel}"
       IsReadOnly="{Binding IsEditable}">
  </DataGrid>  

  <DataGrid
       DataContext="{StaticResource SomeViewModel}"
       IsReadOnly="{Binding IsEditable}">
   </DataGrid>
```